# Flutter cubit2cubit communication

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc

I have a `CandidateListCubit` that holds a list of candidates in a success state(`CandidateListSuccess`). I also have `DecideCandidateCubit`. The function of this cubit is to give the admin the authority to participate or not to participate in any candidate.

What I am trying to do: If the admin accepts or rejects the candidate, then I want to remove the candidate from the list. This is basically cubit-to-cubit communication. However, I couldn't set up a communication between them.

***DecideCandidateCubit***

```
class DecideCandidateCubit extends Cubit<DecideCandidateState> {
  final DecideCandidateUseCase decideCandidateUseCase;
  final CandidateListCubit candidateListCubit;

  DecideCandidateCubit(this.decideCandidateUseCase, this.candidateListCubit) : super(DecideCandidateInitial());

  void decideCandidate(String eventId, AppUser candidate, bool decision) async {
    try {
      emit(DecideCandidateLoading());
      await decideCandidateUseCase.call(eventId, candidate.appUserId!, decision);
    candidateListCubit.removeCandidate(candidate);
    } on ApplicationException catch (e) {
      emit(DecideCandidateFailure(e));
    }
  }
}
```

***CandidateListCubit***

```
class CandidateListCubit extends Cubit<CandidateListState> {
  final GetCandidatesList getCandidatesList;

  CandidateListCubit({required this.getCandidatesList}) : super(CandidateListInitial());

  getCandidates(eventId) async {
    try {
      emit(CandidateListLoading());
      final Map<AppUser, String> map = await getCandidatesList.call(eventId);
      emit(CandidateListSuccess(candidatesMap: map));
    } on ApplicationException catch (e) {
      emit(CandidateListFailure(e));
    }
  }

  void removeCandidate(AppUser candidate) {
    if (state is CandidateListSuccess) {
      final currentSuccessState = state as CandidateListSuccess;
      final Map<AppUser, String> updatedCandidatesMap = Map.from(currentSuccessState.candidatesMap);

      // Remove the candidate from the map
      updatedCandidatesMap.remove(candidate);

      // Create a new CandidateListSuccess state with the updated map
      emit(currentSuccessState.copyWith(candidatesMap: updatedCandidatesMap));
    }
  }
}
```

I debug my code and I see the `candidateListCubit`  is in the initial state not in the success state(even if I successfully fetch the list, and see it on the screen). It seems that a new cubit is created, not the one that is provided is used. How can I set up a communication? I see that 'StreamSubscription' is used, but I couldn't adapt it to my code.

I only make it work like this. In the UI, after calling `decideCandidate`, if I call `removeCandidate` method. But I want to set up a communication inside `DecideCandidateCubit`, not in the UI level.